# Protect a directory if remote host is/is not

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, directory

How can I protect a directory within .htaccess only if the remote host is not 192.168.1.11 ?
Below is how I actually protect directories:

```
AuthUserFile /home/personal/.htpasswd
AuthName "Auth Area"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

I just want to add a condition, for example:

```
if(REMOTE_HOST != 192.168.1.11)
{
    AuthUserFile /home/personal/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Auth Area"
    AuthType Basic
    require valid-user
}
else
{
    AuthUserFile /home/personal/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Admin Area"
    AuthType Basic
    require user admin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK
htaccess will not do any kind of logic like that.

If all you have to work with is the .htaccess files your best bet is to do that sort of thing in programming.